# Symfony Dynamically modify a form

Tags: symfony

I'm setting up new form with 2 fields, Area and city.

and want to setup when Area chosen, will give the list of supported city for Area id.

I Configure ManyToOne on City to Area.

My Form Builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('area', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'App:Area',
            'choice_label' => 'getName',
        ])
    $builder->get('area')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\City',
                'choices' => $form->getData()->getCity()
            ]);
        }
    );

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            $city = $data->getCity();

            if ($city) {
                $form->get('area')->setData($city->getCity);
                $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\City',
                    'choices' => $city->getArea->getCity()
                ]);
            } else {
                $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => '\App\Entity\City',
                    'choices' => $city->getArea->getCity()
                ]);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

City Entity:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class City
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Area")
 */
private $area;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getArea(): ?Area
{
    return $this->area;
}

public function setArea(?Area $area): self
{
    $this->area = $area;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Area Entity:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Area
 {
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}
}
```

I expect when i change the the Area it will give me only the city of area.

After a lot of tries.

now i have the error:

Call to a member function getCity() on null

I try also to add to FormBuilder

```
        ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'App:City',
            'choice_label' => 'getName',
        ])
```

Comment: You are setting $city->getCity in your area tag, and this function doesn't exist in your entity.. shouldn't it be $city->getArea() ? 

Then in your choices you do 

    'choices' => $city->getArea->getCity()

Here, you call getCity on Area, but this entity has no getCity() function.
And are you sure about your POST_SUBMIT form event in the first field? I would do a PRE_SET data and inside the POST SUBMIT.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener of the field should be

```
$form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
```

Comment: it doesn't help